# Centering a UIView

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios, uiview

I'm new to Cocca and IOS development and find myself in the following situation.

I have a background image thats 1024x1024 and I want to display it on all views. I have put the following code in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the app delegate and it loads correctly and is viewable beneath all views.

The problem I have is I can't seem to center the background UIView

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Setup background image for all views
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: window.frame];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-image.png"]];
[window addSubview : backgroundView];
[backgroundView release];


// Override point for customization after application launch.
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

I have managed to move the background UIView to various positions but not center.

I would appriciate any help with this.

Thanks in advance
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your code with ...

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-image.png"]];
backgroundView.frame = window.frame;
[window addSubview:backgroundView];
[backgroundView release];
```

... and try to play with `backgroundView`'s `autoresizingMask` and `contentMode` if your background-image.png doesn't fit the whole window.

Comment: Many Thanks for the reply @Chiefly Izzy, your code and the addition of

 backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

Did what i needed.

Comment: This is not how it should work: `backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`. Instead, you should use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`. You messed up the enum types.

Answer (score 0):

To center the image use the setFrame method, to keep it centered use the autoresizingMask property

```
enum {
   UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
};
```